# Qt4: How to get selected index in QTreeView

Tags: qt, qt4, qtreeview

I have a program that has a tree of directories that open into subtrees of files within those directories. There are two columns in my view: 
     - the tree itself
     - and a text column next to it that says whether the file was selected
- The user can pick multiple files at once. After the user is done selecting, when they hit the "ok" button, the text should change to "selected" next to the appropriate files. 
- The problem is, I can't figure out a way to tell it which indices to change the text of. I tried `selectionModel()->selectedIndexes() (and selectedRows)` but neither of these have a way to get the original index far as I can tell. How could I get the original from the overall tree?

Answer (score 2):

As mumush mentions, Andrea's answer applies to the [QTreeWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) only, not a [QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html). QTreeView has no selectedItems method so you have to use selectedIndexes, which will return you a list of [QModelIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html) objects.

You can use these objects to access and update items in your tree model like so:

```
# Get the fields that are currently selected and loop over them
indexes = tree.selectedIndexes()
for index in indexes:
    # We only care about the "Selected" column.
    if index.column() != 1:
        continue

    # Change the tree value. 
    treeModel.setData(index, "[SELECTED]")
```

Comment: note that selectedIndexes() is a protected member of QTreeView, so this is only possible for custom derrived classes, not a QTreeView instance.

Comment: Oh, this works fine for me on a QTreeView instance, but that may be because I'm using PySide. But if it's protected in core Qt, that makes me wonder if there's a more preferred way to do it with an actual QTreeView? Or is it assumed that everyone using the QTreeView will subclass it?

Comment: on the C++ side there is a selectionModel() public member on which selectedIndexes() can be called.

Comment: Makes sense. :) Maybe you should add it as an answer, since it's better than both of the ones already up.